# What is the wiring of arduino motor shield to Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, shields, arduino-motor-shield

I have the basic version of the [stepper motor driver](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-l293d-motor-drive-shield-for-arduino-duemilanove-mega-uno-r3-avr-atmel.html) and a Nano, I see the pins are set to plug directly in to a Uno or similar Arduino, but according to the documentation it just needs most of the digital pins connected to the arduino - https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/faq

As it seems they are the opposite position to plug into a breadboard for testing, I may need to wire and solder them (11 to D11, 3 to D3, 5 to D5, 6 to D6). Is this correct or does the Nano not have the power/amperage/timing or something to run this type of shield, hence the lack of compatibility listed for that shield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this does work with the Nano - the only reason they don't list it is because it doesn't fit in to the shield I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, though it's not clear, that the shield in question uses a 74HC595 shift register to control the main motor drivers - the other pins are for the servo interfaces (and they are just wired 1:1). Theoretically you can therefore use any pins you like to control the motor drivers themselves.

It's not the same as the Adafruit one which looks to use direct Arduino control of the motor drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Look up the docs for "L293D Motor Drive Shield For Arduin" and it looks like it's the old Adafruit shield, and uses specific pins for each motor... If that's all the difference I guess I'll connect/solder them to the Nano and try.

Answer (score 0):

Or just another simple version (which is more hardcore such as brute force):
Get expansion shield for nano to uno :)

I think this is just a sandwich version, which just takes additional space and cost.